# Prevent IFrame Navigation

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I use an `iframe` to display HTML email contents by writing a HTML string to it's content document via JS. I don't want the user to navigate inside that `iframe` if he clicks a link in the displayed email. Now I have these options:

1. Open links in a new browser window or tab (**preferred**)
2. Prevent all navigation (suboptimal, only if no other option left)
3. Better option I don't know about?

How could I accomplish any of those 2 options?

I know that `HTML5` introduced a `sandbox` property, but unfortunately that only works in `Chrome` and `Safari`, so that's not an option.

Comment: convert all links to spans with onclick events

Comment: If you are writing the html for the iframe document, you should be able to put a <base target="_blank"> element in the head. This will open a new window or tab for links clicked in the iframe.

Comment: Didn't know that I could set a target in `base`. You should have posted this as an answer.

Comment: sandbox property of iframes is now supported by IE10+ and all major browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=iframe-sandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through all the links in the iframe and add `target="_blank"` to them.

(Excuse me but I only know how to do this in JQuery so sorry for linking the example in this without it being tagged in the question):

```
$("#iframeID").contents().find("a").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("target", "_blank");
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/yP7Nd/ - (ignore the bit of JS above my JQuery code, I had to do this to get some IFrame content to load properly).

Comment: I guess this is the most elegant solution, but ultimately it would not prevent navigation events triggered via JS. Perhaps I should also remove all `onclick` etc. events too, but I'm unsure how to do that, if the event handler is added after the script is loaded inside the iframe.

Comment: This won't work if the frame is cross-origin.

Comment: Note the OP: `I use an iframe to display HTML email contents by writing a HTML string to it's content document via JS`. He was setting the content himself so the answer wouldn't apply to cross-origin. Unless you control the source, you can never do anything with the iFrame content.

Answer (score 4):

If the iframe is from a different origin, this method will prevent navigation by resetting the iframe source if it changes:

```
  var $iframe = $('iframe');
  var iframeUrl = 'http://example.com/foo';
  var iframeLoaded = false;
  $iframe.on('load', function () {
    if (!iframeLoaded) {  # Allow initial load of iframe.
      iframeLoaded = true;
      return;
    }

    # Reset iframe location back to original source to prevent navigation.
    iframeLoaded = false;
    $iframe[0].src = iframeUrl;
  });
```

Unfortunately, there's no way to detect the *start* of the iframe load, so it'll briefly flash the new content before navigating back. Also, be aware that this will break the browser back button.

Answer (score 3):

For the page the iframe is hosted in, define a [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) that restricts the [`child-src`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/child-src) to a specific source, such as a domain. FYI this doesn't work for Internet Explorer. Here's a related [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/153404/214065).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to replace all links with their displayed text, something like:

```
var links = document.links;
var i = links.length;
var link, text, node;

while (i--) {
  link = links[i];
  text = link.textContent || link.innerText || '';
  node = document.createTextNode(text);
  link.parentNode.replaceChild(node, link);
}
```

Note that the [links collection](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#dom-document-links) is live, hence the reverse loop.

Comment: Will this work on all browsers? (I ask as the document you linked is Html 5 and the OP says's he wanted to avoid that).

Comment: `document.links` is DOM 0, the DOM methods are all version 2 or earlier, all browsers since about NN or IE 5 support those. The most recent is `textContent` or `innerText`, but I think anything from IE 6 or Firefox 1.5 onward should do it.