# Restrict or prevent iframe navigation

Tags: javascript, html, security, iframe

I have a top page which contains an iframe with untrusted content. I am hosting the untrusted content on a domain that I control, and can (in theory) make changes to it. Short of analyzing the source code with something like Google Caja, is there any way that I can prevent the untrusted content from navigating the frame itself to other URLs? (or ideally restrict it to the trusted domain)

Related, but not quite:

- [Only addresses anchor tags, not navigation in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259673/prevent-iframe-navigation)
- Lots and lots of webpages talking about sandbox with "allow-top-navigation". Doesn't help because I want to restrict navigation of the frame itself

**Background:** My goal is to allow untrusted content to run in the iframe and to pass some user data to it, but I don't want the untrusted content to turn around and send this data to a 3rd-party. (The content will be allowed instead to postMessage any results to an API exposed by the parent window.) Content Security Policy HTTP headers on the untrusted content allow me to restrict all manner of network requests *except* navigation.

Answer (score 1):

I randomly saw this new Content Security Policy option hinted at on MDN (with a little flask on it, so may still be experimental...)

`navigation-to`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy